# Cannot push data to mysql

Tags: mysql, database

I can't seem to push data from my form to the database, I have checked the error_log and there's no error.  Please check my codes below, thank you!

```
<?php 
   $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","admineventus","J7!ren;3") or Die ("Cannot connect");
    mysqli_select_db($con,"eventus");


if(isset($_POST['submitpublish']))
   {
  mysqli_query($con,"insert into events values('$_POST[Category]','$_POST[Name]','$_POST[Location]','$_POST[Sdate]','$_POST[Edate]','$_POST[Etime]','$_POST[Fee]','$_POST[Free]','$_POST[About]')");
     }
                 ?>
```

Comment: Are your code even going in the IF? Are all fields in the right order for the insert command? (it is always better to explicit the columns like `insert into someTable (col1, col2, ...., coln) values ( val1, val2, ..., valn );`) and the `$_POST` usage is `$_POST["NameVar"]` with double/single quotes

Comment: Can you also post the code of the form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
if(isset($_POST['submitpublish']))
 {
 $sql = "INSERT INTO events (col1, col1, .. , colx)
VALUES ('".$_POST["Category"]."','".$_POST["Name"]."','".$_POST["Location"]."','".$_POST["Sdate"]."','".$_POST["Sdate"]."','".$_POST["Edate"]."','".$_POST["Etime"]."','".$_POST["Fee"]."','".$_POST["Free"]."','".$_POST["About"]."')";

 $result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
 }
```

Make sure your code enters in `IF` statement